# Use image url with add_image_size

Tags: urls, images

I am looking for a way to use an image url with the WordPress function `add_image_size`,  I have already setup an image size called `'custom-thumb'` For example, instead of...

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'custom-thumb' );
```

Which would output the posts thumbnail at the custom size I specified, I want to do something like...

```
www.mydomain.com/image.jpg('custom-thumb');
```

Comment: `add_image_size` adds a size for WordPress to use when generating thumbnails. I don't see how using an URL even comes into that.

Comment: Correct, add_image_size adds a size for WordPress to use.  I now want to output an image at that size by its WordPress URL.  Make sense?

Comment: No, still doesn't make sense. What does "output an image at that size by its WordPress URL" mean? You want to _display_ an image at that size, but how does the URL get involved?

Comment: I have updated the original post to try and better explain the question

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you posted...

```
www.mydomain.com/image.jpg('custom-thumb');
```

... is a bit odd. That would be pretty tricky. You'd need a PHP handler to load the image and you'd need to tell the server (Apache, Nginx, IIS, Whatever) to parse that file ending as PHP. Something like this would be simpler:

```
www.mydomain.com/image.php?size=custom-thumb
```

You would still need to create a PHP handler script to read the URL, parse the `GET` string, and display the image.

You could probably get something like this...

```
www.mydomain.com/image/custom-thumb-X
```

... working with an [endpoint](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint).

However, the easiest thing to do is use `wp_get_attachment_image_src` to create the URL. I don't know if that is an option for you but there is an example in the Codex:

```
<?php 
$attachment_id = 8; // attachment ID

$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id ); // returns an array
?> 

<img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attributes[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attributes[2]; ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

[TimThumb](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/projects/timthumb/) ([source code](http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/)) is probably what you *think* you need, and probably good enough now, considering that it's been a while since it was last exploited. Like anything else, it comes with its own pros/cons (just google 'em).

But you should know that once you get the hang of [`add_image_size` and `the_post_thumbnail` functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails) you'll never have to go back.

**PS:** Besides it looks like an XY problem. So, considering that you think **X** is the solution to problem **Y**, why don't you tell us more about **Y**, and see if we can suggest a better alternative to **X**?